# Is Broker a design pattern and mentioned in Design Patterns by Gamma et al.?

Tags: design-patterns, architectural-patterns

In the book [*Software Architecture in Practice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-II73rBDXCYC&lpg=PT306&ots=ZnVyPJdmUx&dq=The%20original%20version%20of%20the%20broker%20pattern%2C%20as%20documented%20by%20Gamma%2C%20Helm%2C%20Johnson%2C%20and%20Vlissides&pg=PT306#v=onepage&q=The%20original%20version%20of%20the%20broker%20pattern,%20as%20documented%20by%20Gamma,%20Helm,%20Johnson,%20and%20Vlissides&f=false) by Bass et al., it is mentioned:

> The broker pattern defines a runtime component, called a broker, that 
>   mediates  the communication between a number of cllents and servers.
>
> The original version of the broker pattern, as documented by Gamma, Helm, Johnson, and Vlissides 
>   [Gamma 94],  is given in Figure  13.6.
>
> [image]

I don't find [the Design Pattern book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) by Gamma et al. includes a pattern called Broker. Is Broker mentioned in Design Patterns by Gamma et al.?

I see Broker is listed as an architectural pattern in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Design_Patterns_patterns).
Is Broker a design pattern or an architectural pattern?